# Creating a remote mysql datasource for vb.net 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datasource

I have mysql database in a server and connected with

`Mysql.Data` library in vb.net, I have all things working, but now I have a problem in producing a report, using crystal reports.

Where do I set the data source of the crystal reports so that I fetched the data from that remote mysql.

Answer (score 0):

There a lots of ways to do this but this is the way I do it. BTW, I have this in a library I use in multiple applications. NOTE: This assumes a SQL Client connection string, you can change this to meet your needs.

```
Public Shared Sub SetupReportConnections(ByVal rpt As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument, ByVal ConnString As String, Optional ByVal UpdateSubReport As Boolean = True)
    If ConnString = "" Then Exit Sub
    'First, parse the connection string for the parts we need
    Dim CN As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString)
    Dim sServer As String = CN.DataSource
    Dim sDatabase As String = CN.Database

    'Update the connection information for each table
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    Dim CrTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables
    Dim CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table

    CrTables = rpt.Database.Tables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = sServer
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next

    If UpdateSubReport Then
        For Each subrpt As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument In rpt.Subreports
            SetupReportConnections(subrpt, ConnString, False)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```